# How To Save Multi Text Box with Wordpress Meta Box

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, metadata, meta-boxes

first sorry for my English.

I Add a Simple Meta Box to My Custom Wordpress Them

Here My add_meta_boxes Code :

```
function download_link_boxes()
 {
   $screens = array('post', 'music');

   foreach ($screens as $screen) {
    add_meta_box('dl_link_box', 'LINKS', 'download_box_content',  $screen);
 }

}
```

Here CallBack Functions :

```
function download_box_content($post)
{
$music_links = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'music-links', 'false');

<input type="text" name="link-music[]" value="<?php echo $music_links ?>">
<input type="text" name="link-music[]" value="<?php echo $music_links ?>">
<input type="text" name="link-music[]" value="<?php echo $music_links ?>">
}
```

And For Update & Save :

```
add_action('save_post', 'save_my_music_links');
function save_my_music_links($post_id)
{

if (!isset($_POST['link-music[]'])) {
    return;
}

if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE' && DOING_AUTOSAVE)){
    return;
}


$my_links = sanitize_text_field($_POST['link-music[]']);
update_post_meta($post_id, 'music-links', $my_links);
}
```

Now, If Change My text Box's Name To 'link-music' Instead 'link-music[]' And Keep Only One text Box It's Work Fine. I Can Add , Update and Delete But For Multi Text Box Nothing happen!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see at a quick glimpse of your code, there are few things that aren't right.

The `download_link_boxes()` function is fine. The other two functions aren't.

Lets start with the `download_box_content()`:

1. Each of your inputs are in php, they can't be inside the php wrappers.
2. As you are trying to store the data of `link-music` as an array, I would expect some sort of a loop to go through each of the values, i.e after you `explode` the variable itself. But in your case, if you are expecting only 3 values, use the array index format to fetch each link

Now to fix the third function, `save_my_music_links()`; You are looking for `link-music` as an array, i.e `link-music[]`. This isn't right. Even if on HTML, you use the square brackets, on PHP, the index in `$_POST` will only be **link-music**. So it should be written as: `$_POST['link-music']`. Also, your `sanitize_text_field` function will convert the Array to string. You might want to loop through each value and sanitize it or use `array_map`

So if you fix those changes you should have something like this in your functions.php:

```
function download_box_content($post)
{
    $music_links = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'music-links', 'false');
    ?>
    <input type="text" name="link-music[]" value="<?php echo isset($music_links[0]) ? $music_links[0] : "" ?>">
    <input type="text" name="link-music[]" value="<?php echo isset($music_links[1]) ? $music_links[1] : "" ?>">
    <input type="text" name="link-music[]" value="<?php echo isset($music_links[2]) ? $music_links[2] : "" ?>">
    <?php
}

add_action('save_post', 'save_my_music_links');
function save_my_music_links($post_id)
{

    if (!isset($_POST['link-music'])) {
        return;
    }

    if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE' && DOING_AUTOSAVE)){
        return;
    }


    $my_links = array_map("sanitize_text_field",$_POST['link-music']);
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'music-links', $my_links);
}
```